# Need to cacade options in dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select, cascadingdropdown

I have 3 dropdowns with same set of options as below

```
<select id="one">
<option value="1">Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
<option value="1">Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="three">
 <option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

If user selects option "one" in third dropdown, "One" should not be displayed in 1nd and 2rd dropdown.
At any point of time when user clicks on any dropdown, only the current value along with the values which are not selected in other dropdown should be displayed.

Is there any way to achieve this with jQuery

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You need to close `<option>` tag using `</option>`

You also need to give different value beside `1` such as `-1` or leave it as blank for the first option inside each of your select

Then you can do like this to achieve your requirements:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option[value="' + selectedVal + '"]').hide();
    $(this).siblings('select').find(':not(option[value="' + selectedVal + '"])').show();
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6DY6z/)**

Comment: Thanks @felix .. this is working as expected. but one additional requirement is... Consider a dropdown has "One" selected. When i change it to "Select", i want "One" to be listed in all other dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using an event listener for your select dropdowns.
In the event listener function get the selected value from the element that triggered the event.

Once you have the selected value, you can loop through other select dropdowns and remove the selected value.

Here is a short snippet of the code

```
    $('.dropdown').change(function (event) {
        $('.dropdown').each(function (index, element) {

            if (event.target.id == element.id) {
                return true;            
            }

            var selectedValue = event.target.value;
            $(element).children('[value=' + selectedValue + ']').remove();
        });
    });
```

Here is a complete working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/399LF/

Comment: Thanks you for your idea. But instead of removing, hiding is a better option as suggested by @felix

Comment: Yes, I agree hiding will be better. You could atleast avoid looping through the options of selected drop down using the if condition as shown in my code above